# WSO2 EMM Reusing mdm certificate

Tags: certificate, wso2, apple-push-notifications, mdm, wso2-iot

I received a certificate for the test server.
Can I use a certificate MDM another server or need to request a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a certificate for your test server and one for your production server. You can request as many parallel (== independent) certificates from Apple.

https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/

Comment: When generating a query to be sent to specify WSO2 "Common Name". It turns MDM APNS certificate is bound to the server?

Comment: The only thing that's bound to a MDM certificate is a device after it's registered for push notifications of that specific certificate. It's definitely not recommended, but you can re-use the same MDM certificate on different servers at the same time. As it doesn't cost anything to generate additional certificates I highly recommend - as stated above - to use dedicated certificates for each environment.